# Self contained publish ASP.NET Core 2.0 app to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0

Is it possible to do a self contained publish for an ASP.NET Core 2.0 app to Azure?

I use the following command line approach to create a publish folder of my WebJobs project and I really like this approach because it gives me full control.

```
dotnet publish --self-contained -r win10-x64 -c Release
```

Can I use the same for my ASP.NET Core 2.0 app? It's important to point out that I have a React frontend. I do, however, manually prepare the frontend files using Webpack.

Currently, I publish the ASP.NET Core app from Visual Studio and I can't say that I'm happy with it. It takes too long and I frequently get errors. I'd much rather go with the self contained publish approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [self-contained deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs#simpleSelf) to create a publish folder of your Asp.net core in local folder.

> Is it possible to do a self contained publish for an ASP.NET Core 2.0 app to Azure?

I think you would publish all the app files in `\bin\Release\` to azure app service.

If so, you could try to [deploy the application using Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-cli?tabs=windows).